# Embed Jetty loading web context issue

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I want to load a web context not by xml, but configure programatically.
If I use the method setwar(), it worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app id = "DERBYNET_ID">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>webAllowOthers</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But, I want to remove webapp. becasuse it has a xml only. So, I want to set the servlet programmatically like below.But, it's not working. I can't see the error log on the console when I run application. But, If I connect the web page, it gives 503 status code. Why this source code doesn't work??

```
        ServletHandler servletHandler = new ServletHandler();

        ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder("H2Console", (Class<? extends Servlet>) WebServlet.class);
        holder.setInitOrder(1);
        holder.setInitParameter("webAllowOthers", "true");

        ServletHolder[] holders = { holder };

        ServletMapping servletMapping = new ServletMapping();
        servletMapping.setServletName("H2Console");
        servletMapping.setPathSpec("/console/*");
        ServletMapping[] servletMappings =  {servletMapping};

        servletHandler.setServlets(holders);
        servletHandler.setServletMappings(servletMappings);

        derbyWebapp.setServletHandler(servletHandler);
```

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: Thanks. I am out of office. The version is about  v9.1.